# Why is my popen failing

Tags: c, popen

My c code is

```
size_t n=0;
char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 1000)
FILE *fp = popen(" cat /conf/a.txt" ,"r" );
// my program comes in this function only if /conf/a.txt exists

getline(&str, &n, fp); <== crash if fp is null
```

My debugger shows that sometimes i get fp as null and hence my program crashes at line 6 . Sometimes i get valid pointere and it passes .

What is it , that controls this behaviour . I can't find problem in above code . Some help is appreciated .

I know I can have a check of fp==null but that is not my question . I just want to know , knowing that file is definitely present why is fp coming as null in some scenarios .

man of popen says `The popen() function returns NULL if the fork(2) or pipe(2) calls fail, or if it cannot allocate memory.`

i checked after crash and system is having enough memory ..

Comment: When `fp` is `NULL` you should check `errno` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: can u please tell me how to do so ?

Comment: Also, what is `r` in `popen(" cat /conf/a.txt" ,r );`? Is it a variable holding `"r"`?

Comment: corrrected  my post . Its "r" ie read stream

Comment: Just check (after `popen` when `fp` is `NULL`) `errno` value and print it out like this: `if (NULL == fp) printf("Error: %d\n", errno)`. Also you should set it to zero before you call `popen`, like this: `errno = 0; FILE* fp = popen(...`. BTW strictly speaking this is C, not C++, I suggest to retag your question!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Strictly speaking it could be either C or C++, but since it doesn't happen to use any C++-specific features it does make sense to tag it as C.

Comment: @KeithThompson ;) 80% source code "named" C can be also compiled in C++ and...20% source code "named" C++ can almost directly compiled in C... LOL

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: And nearly 0% *good* C++ source code can be compiled as C.

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree, that's why I said "named" C++...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strerror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strerror/) and [errno](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) are your friends.

Example from the C++ references linked:

```
/* strerror example : error list */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("unexist.ent","r");
  if (pFile == NULL)
    printf ("Error opening file unexist.ent: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

> Error opening file unexist.ent: No such file or directory

Using this method of checking errno after a failure will allow you to better diagnose your issue as it will print a more specific error message. There are many reasons a file can't be opened: no permission, bad path, file is locked from another process, IO errors during reading, etc. Ultimately your question seems to be asking why the open failed. Using these tools will answer that for you.

Update For Tag Change:

I've referenced and linked to C++ resources, but sterror and errno are both available in C as well by including errno.h.

Comment: And `popen` (which is defined by POSIX but not by the C or C++ standard) behaves similarly to `fopen`.

Comment: Error number : 12
Error opening file unexist.ent: Cannot allocate memory .. But my system is having enough memory# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24444       4658      19786          0        192       3658
-/+ buffers/cache:        808      23636
Swap:            0          0          0

Comment: There's your answer! Memory allocation failed. Now your next step is to research the causes of memory allocation errors when using popen in C. Note that the error message is *not* "out of memory". It is "memory allocation failed". Memory allocation can fail for more reasons than just not having enough memory.

Comment: can u specify some reasons as well ? Accepting you answer :)

Comment: I know that popen will return the mem allocation failed error if you've hit the system limit on open file descriptors. Are you opening your files in any loops without closing them, or opening many at once?

Comment: Also, how big is your file? popen will try to pass you the output through a pipe, and you may be filling up the pipe with the output from cat, causing it to fail.

Comment: mine is a 20Kb file . ALso this function is not having any loops  . Is this error related to open file handles alone ? In case i am actually leaking up memory allocations somewhere else , will i get the same error ??

Answer (score 1):

popen() also fails if too many file handles are open in one process. I had one case in a server app, that was scanning one directory periodically for files.There was one scenario were no fclose call was made. So after some hours we reached the limit of 1024 open file handles on from that moment consecutive popen() calls would fail.

You can use ps -aux | grep {PROC_NAME} to retrieve the process id.
Then use sudo ls -l /proc/{PROC_ID}/fd to see the list of open file descriptors.

Comment: Late to the party - but for future readers, this IMHO should have been the accepted answer.  It is likely caused by failing to call pclose() after you're done with the file handle - I'm unsure if fclose is just as sufficient, but pclose seems more proper based on naming conventions alone.    For Windows users, you can see how many children your executable is spawning by finding your process in the "processes" tab and expanding the tree. (1024 seems to be the Windows handle limit as well, at which point you'll start getting NULL back).